connecting two external monitors with Ubuntu 22.04
I know this question has been addressed several times but I can't find the right answer to my problem -- sorry for posting again about this.
I have a HP Elitebook with a a Mesa Intel GPU. The OS is Ubuntu 22.04.
I can plug one external monitor with the built-in HDMI port of the laptop. This works. I want to plug a second HDMI monitor through one of the USB-C port, with a USB-C/HDMI adaptor.
This used to work, and it suddenly stopped working, I have no idea why.
This is NOT a cable or adapter issue. They all work when tested separately.
What are the software solutions I should try?
Everything I read is about Nvidia, not Intel GPU.
Thanks!
